# Facebook Share Link Not Correct

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

I have a WordPress site that when you click the Facebook like button it likes the wrong url.

If I inspect the web page, the url that is inside the like widget is always the same URL no matter what post you are on. It is like one of the posts url is being set somewhere.

I have checked and it ONLY does it for posts, not pages.

I feel like I have found the area (might be wrong) but I believe it is here in the loop

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : 

                    $post = $posts[0]; // Hack. Set $post so that the_date() works. ?>
                    <?php /* If this is a category archive */ if (is_category()) { ?>
                  <h3><?php printf(__('Archive for the &#8216;%s&#8217; Category', TEXTDOMAIN), single_cat_title('', false)); ?></h3>
                    <?php /* If this is a tag archive */ } elseif( is_tag() ) { ?>
                  <h3><?php printf(__('Posts Tagged &#8216;%s&#8217;', TEXTDOMAIN), single_tag_title('', false) ); ?></h3>
                    <?php /* If this is a daily archive */ } elseif (is_day()) { ?>
                  <h3><?php printf(__('Archive for %s | Daily archive page', TEXTDOMAIN), get_the_time(__('F jS, Y', TEXTDOMAIN))); ?></h3>
                    <?php /* If this is a monthly archive */ } elseif (is_month()) { ?>
                  <h3><?php printf(__('Archive for %s | Monthly archive page', TEXTDOMAIN), get_the_time(__('F Y', TEXTDOMAIN))); ?></h3>
                    <?php /* If this is a yearly archive */ } elseif (is_year()) { ?>
                  <h3><?php printf(__('Archive for %s | Yearly archive page', TEXTDOMAIN), get_the_time(__('Y', TEXTDOMAIN))); ?></h3>
                    <?php /* If this is a yearly archive */ } elseif (is_search()) { ?>
                  <h3><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', TEXTDOMAIN ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h3>
                   <?php /* If this is an author archive */ } elseif (is_author()) { ?>               
                  <h3><?php _e('Author Archive', TEXTDOMAIN); ?></h3>
                    <?php /* If this is a paged archive */ } elseif (isset($_GET['paged']) && !empty($_GET['paged'])) { ?>
                  <h3><?php _e('Blog Archives', TEXTDOMAIN); ?></h3>        
                    <?php } 

                      while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

                        global $more;

                        if(!is_single()) $more = 0;

                        $type_blog = ( $GLOBALS['yiw_custom_blog_type'] != false ) ? $GLOBALS['yiw_custom_blog_type'] : get_option( $GLOBALS['shortname'] . '_blog_type', 'classic' );
                    ?>
```

It is setting the $post but I am not sure how to fix it or check that this is in fact it. If I remove it, the page does not work.

Any help here will help a lot, if I am not correct what else should I be looking for?

The following are also areas in the functions.php that have the $post in it

```
function catch_that_image() {
    global $post, $posts;
    $first_img = '';
    ob_start();
    ob_end_clean();
    $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
    $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

    if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
      $first_img = get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/images/default.gif";
    }
    return $first_img;
}
```

and

```
    function get_current_ID()
{
    global $post;
    return $post->ID;
}

function get_current_pagename()
{
    global $post;
    return $post->post_name;
}
```

Comment: it will be in a js file somewhere....

Comment: @David any idea what to look for if it is not above? I might have to pay someone to do it for me but I would like to do it if I can.

Comment: yes if you post the link ill have a quick look for you.

Comment: Thank @David and example is this link goo.gl/7SSy4f - the facebook like widget on floating sidebar links to the wrong URL

Comment: this is the line you need to change -- its in the footer - `<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.socialmediology.com.au/twitter-releases-firsttweet-tool3/" data-width="50" data-height="62" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>` so it could be added using the the functions file using `enqueue_scripts` or added into the footer itself. Bear in mind it will be using php to create the line so best thing to do is search your files for class="fb-like" (most text editors will let you search all files in a location)